# Solving $- \Delta u = \lambda u + |u|^{q-2} u$ by method of Langrange's multipliers

Tags: proof-explanation, calculus-of-variations, lagrange-multiplier

Let $\lambda < \lambda_1$ and $ 2 < q < 2^*$. I am trying solve this problem

$$(P) \begin{align}
\begin{cases}
-\Delta u &= \lambda u + |u|^{q-2} u \ \text{in} \ \Omega,\\
u &= 0 \ \text{on} \ \partial \Omega.
\end{cases}
\end{align}$$

I was able to find a non-trivial and positive solution for the auxiliary problem:

$$(P') \begin{align}
\begin{cases}
-\Delta u &= \lambda u + \theta |u|^{q-2} u \ \text{in} \ \Omega,\\
u &= 0 \ \text{on} \ \partial \Omega,
\end{cases}
\end{align}$$

where $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ was obtained by the method of Lagrange's multipliers.

My question is how can I find a solution of the problem $(P)$ from the solution of the problem $(P')$?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let be $u$ the solution of the problem $(P')$ and let be $t > 0$. Define $\overline{u} := t u$. On the one hand,

$$- \Delta \overline{u} = t (- \Delta u) = t (\lambda u + \theta |u|^{q-2} u).$$

On the other hand,

$$\lambda \overline{u} + |\overline{u}|^{q-2} \overline{u} = \lambda t u + t^{q-1} |u|^{q-2} u.$$

We want to show that $\overline{u}$ is a solution of the problem $(P)$, i.e.,

$$- \Delta \overline{u} = \lambda \overline{u} + |\overline{u}|^{q-2} \overline{u}.$$

Suppose the equality above holds, then

$$t (\lambda u + \theta |u|^{q-2} u) = \lambda t u + t^{q-1} |u|^{q-2} u.$$

Thus, we need to have $t = \theta^{\frac{1}{q-2}}$ in order to $\overline{u}$ be the solution of the problem $(P)$.